# When second Click on Button do something

Tags: javascript, events, button, click, dom-events

I need that when a button is clicked once it will show the message "Don't show". And when clicked twice returns to the original message "Show". The first thing I already did it, I only need help with the second thing, that being the second click.

**JavaScript:**

```
function show()
{
    document.myform.button.value ="Dont show";//Changes message on button when clicked.
    document.myform.button.innerHTML= "Dont show";
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form>
<input type=button value= "Show" name="button" id= "idButton"
onClick="show()">
</form>
```

Comment: When you were typing your question, there was this handy box to the right titled **How to Format**. Worth a read, as is the information available from the **[?]** button above the question text area. I've fixed the code formatting for you this time.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
function toggle(el, message1, message2) {
    if (!el || !message1 || !message2) {
        return false;
    }
    var text = el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input' ? el.value : (el.textContent || el.innerText),
        newText = text == message1 ? message2 : message1;

    if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input') {
        el.value = newText;
    }
    else {
        el.firstChild.nodeValue = newText;
    }
}

document.getElementById('idButton').onclick = function(){
    toggle(this, 'Show', "Don't show");
};
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MYwNh/).

A slightly revised version of the above:

```
function isTag(el, tagname) {
    if (!el || !tagname) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return el.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagname.toLowerCase() ? true : false;
    }
}

function toggle(el, message1, message2) {
    if (!el || !message1 || !message2) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var isInput = isTag(el, 'input'),
            text = isInput ? el.value : el.textContent || el.innerText,
            newText = text == message1 ? message2 : message1;
        if (isInput) {
            el.value = newText;
        }
        else if (el.textContent) {
            el.textContent = newText;
        }
        else {
            el.innerText = newText;
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById('idButton').onclick = function(){
    toggle(this, 'Show', "Don't show");
};
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MYwNh/1/).

Comment: Also, Show/Hide would probably be a better terminology than Show/Don't show.

Comment: Agreed, but I leave that to the OP to customise according to his design. The functionality's there for him to do so... =)

Comment: Thanks but its still not working for me. I copied your functions unaltered. But they are not working. Do they work for you?

Comment: Of course they work for me, if they didn't then I wouldn't have posted them as an answer. Do the demos that I linked to (in the answer, below the code-blocks) work for you?

Comment: They work for me when I try it on the demos. But when I copy the code to Dreamweaver and execute it, it doesnt.

Comment: They work for me when I try it on the demos. But when I copy the code to Dreamweaver and execute it in a browser, it doesnt. Ive tried Mozilla and Chrome.

Comment: Here it is:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242949/heres-the-dreamweaver-code

Answer (score 0):

Your function show needs to examine the current button value and set it to the appropriate new value.

I assume the missing braces around the body of the show function are a typo.